# Image cropper not saving cropped Image in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-image-cropper

I'm using `ngx-image-cropper`

```
import { ImageCroppedEvent, ImageTransform } from 'ngx-image-cropper';
user={ ..
};
image: any = '';
croppedImage: any = '';
transform: ImageTransform = {};
scale = 1;
showCropper = false;
profilePicUpload(e): void {
    this.imageChangedEvent = e;
    this.image  = e.target.files[0];
  }

  imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.user.photo = event.base64;
    this.croppedImage = event.base64.substring(22);
  }
  imageLoaded() {
    this.showCropper = true;
  }

async addImg() {

 if(this.image){ 
      const path  = await this.UploadService.uploadFile(this.image);
      await new Promise(f => setTimeout(f, 2000));
      this.user.photo = '';
      this.user.photo += path;
     } 
}
```

using this code to upload image but issue is the cropped image is not saved but the original image is saved.

Any solution Thanks

Comment: I have used npm package version->"ngx-image-cropper": "^3.2.0" it is working fine. you have to import ImageCropperModule in imports array.
Here is the method in component.ts file. 
imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.croppedImage = event.base64;
  }

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should upload the cropped image `this.croppedImage`?

```js
this.UploadService.uploadFile(this.croppedImage);
```

Comment: Thanks if i use `this.croppedImage` getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')` in this line of service : `var name = file.name.split('.')[0] + '_' + currentdate.getDate()`

Comment: Can i convert base64 to image and then upload the image

Answer (score 0):

```
this.croppedImageUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(event.objectUrl);
```

try this

source : https://github.com/Mawi137/ngx-image-cropper/releases/tag/7.0.0